# How do I get values from a FlexiGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I can't seem to find anything on how to get a cells' value from a flexigrid.

I am trying to retrieve the third columns' cell value for every checked item.(each row has a checkbox).

I have a function that gets the rows id, but I cannot get it to work for the third column.
(Since it is a flexigrid you can rearrange things so third column won't always be third column)

Here is my function:

```
function getSelectedExhibitIDs() {
        var selectedExhibitsList = new Array;
        var exhibitNumber = new Array;
        var i = 0;
        $('.exhibitCheckBox:checked').each(function () {
            if ($(this)[0].id !== "checkAllExhibits") {
                selectedExhibitsList[i] = $(this)[0].id.split('_')[1];
                ++i;
            }
        });
        return selectedExhibitsList;
    }
```

Comment: I don't work with Flexigrid, but you don't need to declare `var i =0` outside of the `$.each` function. the `$.each` function accepts `two parameters`. The first is the index, and the 2nd is the object. In this case, you could just do `.each(function(i)` which will achieve the same results without having to create an incrementing variable within the iterator.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not trying to access the 3rd Column at all..

```
$('.exhibitCheckBox:checked').each(function (i) {
   if ($(this)attr('id') !== "checkAllExhibits") {

        // This will take you to the parent tr in which the checked checkbox is
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        //Need to find the 3rd cell in the current row

        var third = $tr.find('watyouwant');

        // Next you need to find the 3rd cell you want and add it to a array
        selectedExhibitsList[i] = third.attr(id).split('_')[1];
    }
});
```

Comment: the function i posted i used as an example. It only gets the ID of the file. I've tried this function but it doesn't seem to have the desired effect. I will try to tinker with it